# Using a geocode script given and getting errors in R

Tags: r, geocoding

I have to perform a geocode script in R.  I have a script given and I have tried to get it to work, but keep getting error.  I am pasting my code below and the errors I am getting.  If you could guide me in the correct direction, I would appreciate it.

```
# initialise a dataframe to hold the results
geocoded <- data.frame()
# find out where to start in the address list (if the script was interrupted before):
startindex <- 1
# if a temp file exists - load it up and count the rows!
tempfilename <- paste0(hw1, '_temp_geocoded.rds')
if (file.exists(tempfilename)){
   print("Found temp file - resuming from index:")
   geocoded <- readRDS(tempfilename)
   startindex <- nrow(geocoded)
   print(startindex)
}

## Warning message:
## In if (file.exists(tempfilename)) { :
##   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, and it shows up because `length(tempfilename)` is greater than 1. It's unclear what you're trying to do but you might want to check that `hw1` and `tempfilename` are what you expect or loop over the elements of `tempfilename`

Comment: Actually, it shows up because `length(file.exists(tempfilename)) > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `file.exists(...)` returns a logical vector of length equal to the length of its argument. So if you provide a vector of file names, `file.exists(...)` will return a vector of the same length, where each element is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether the corresponding file exists.

The problem is that `if(...)` expects a scalar (vector of length 1). Otherwise, it just uses the first element of the vector and gives the warning you are seeing.

So, I suspect that `hw1` is a vector of length > 1, which will make `tempfilename` a vector of length > 1.